# Strange behaviour for comments in Antlr4 grammar

Tags: comments, antlr4

When adding a comment line under `ID` is ok, however adding one under `WS`, causes an error to be raised. Entire file `Hello.g4` listed below.

```
/**
 * Define a grammar called Hello
 */
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier

ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers
/**********************************************************************************************/

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

/**********************************************************************************************/
```

The output i get in the console is as below:

```
ANTLR Tool v4.4 (/tmp/antlr-4.4-complete.jar)
Hello.g4 -o /home/me/workspace/TestComment/target/generated-sources/antlr4 -listener -no-visitor -encoding UTF-8
error(50): Hello.g4:13:0: syntax error: '<EOF>' came as a complete surprise to me
1 error(s)

BUILD FAIL
Total time: 168 millisecond(s)
```

Running Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), Default ANTLR4 project.

Why should ANTLR4, care about a trailing comment line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANTLR 4 grammar defines JavaDoc comments as optionally allowed as a header and on each rule. No rule follows the last 'comment line', so it is interpreted an invalid beginning of a rule.

Change your comment line to `/*----*/` to avoid the error.